# How to link to jquery mobile subpage from external page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a basic jQuery Mobile page like so:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

</div>
<div data-role="page" id="products">

</div>
```

All works as expected unless I want to link to the products page from an external link.  I've tried:
mysite.com/mobile/default.aspx#products but that only displays the home page.  Is there a way for an external link to make the products page to show?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126767/jquery-mobile-internal-hash-links-not-working

Comment: that is about linking OUT of a jqm site ... this post is about linking into a jqm subpage ... EX: maybe I want to give my friend a link directly to the fruits 'page' of my grocery store site ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot directly link to a specific page within a *multipage document*.

Unfortunately the way jQuery Mobile works is that when you link to a page with multiple "pages" it will by default only load the first *page*, to load the entire external multipage doc you need to either load the page without ajax (for example adding `rel="external"`, or if you want to load the page with ajax you can use the [subpages plugin](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget).

As far as linking goes you should either separate your *pages*, or preload the external multipage document via ajax (using the plugin I linked to above, or manually if you are so inclined) and then link to it as an internal page.

From the [Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

> It's important to note that if you are linking from a mobile page that
>   was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages,
>   you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link.
>   This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the
>   Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash
>   (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the
>   hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.
>
> For example, a link to a page containing multiple internal pages would look like this:

```
<a href="multipage.html" rel="external">Multi-page link</a>
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the answer is it?? This answer is discussing linking from one jqm site to another jqm site. But that does me no good if I email my friend a link to a subpage of my site.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd what exactly do you mean **you** don't think this is the answer? this is an answer to the question *Steve Meyer* had, and apparently it did answer **his** question since he marked it as accepted.

Comment: I suppose it answers it implicitly, basically saying, 'No, it can't be done. If you want that capability then jqm's 'page' architecture is not right for you.'

so maybe so ... as far as Steve accepting ... I have noticed that people will often accept an answer just because they feel that they must do so to get their points.

Comment: I guess the main thing that turned me off of this answer was the ajax discussion. Ajax is not relevant in most site-linking scenarios, such as when a person is simply sharing a link with someone. I can't email my buddy a link to subpage = 'baseball hats' and then tell him to copy/paste it into an html/js file with ajax features. The OP clearly indicated that this was the situation that he was concerned about.

Comment: I think it's pretty explicit in that if you want to have such links then you can't use the **multipage** setup, *unless* you preload your external pages (that is of course only an option if you are controlling the external page to). The question was not about emailing a link, in that case yes you would need to use a single page setup, or have your page load the appropriate external pages on page load).

Comment: please see the new answer .. jqm offers a data-url attribute that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

for each 'page' add a data-url attribute with the same name as you give the id:

```
<div data-role  = 'page'                         
     id         = 'page_baseball_hats'  
     data-url   = 'page_baseball_hats'    
  >
```

then you should be able to direct link from *outside* the site into a 'subpage' using the url hash system that jqm already generates, such as: www.myjqmsite.com/#page_baseball_hats

The second paragraph introduces this idea: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Comment: First off I don't think you need to add the `data-url` [yourself](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html). Aside from that this will only work if you are doing a full post (i.e `rel="external"`).

Comment: @Jack ... until I **manually** added the data-url's, __www.myjqmsite.com/#my_subpage__ did not work for me

Comment: something that is confusing about this thread is that it seems that there are two different conversations going on: **conv_01:** about some website_Z.com that includes links to a_multipage_jqm_site.com; **conv_02:** about a_direct_url_format that directs a browser to a_multipage_jqm_site.com/#a_subpage. ... ... I am responding to the second issue ... now I am not sure what the OP actually had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is an outside of the box way.. But works well.

```
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mainPage', function (e) {  
      if(window.location.hash) {
          $('#YOUR BTN ID LINKED TO DESIRED SUBPAGE').click();
      } 
  });
```

This says "if your url has a hash (index.html#subPage), and if you have a hyperlink button to that page with an id (set that id to the $click), (you may have this button in your navbar in your footer for example) go to that subPage before the mainPage is displayed"

Change the #mainPage to the first page id in your multipage url.

Change #subPage to the subpage id in your multipage url.

Of course this will only work if you only have one subpage.

If you have multiple sub pages, use this

```
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mainPage', function (e) {  
      var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");
      if(window.location.hash) {
          if(hash === 'subPage'){ 
              $('#YOUR BTN ID LINKED TO DESIRED SUBPAGE').click(); 
          }
      }
  });
```