# linking the 2nd div page in html

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a `link.html` and `back.html` and in `link.html` I have 2 pages

**link.html**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <img src="first.png">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<img src="second.png">
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

and in **back.html** i have a single div page

```
<div data-role="page" id="back">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#" data-role="button">back
</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<img src="fire.png">
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

Is their a way when i click on back button i can display the page2 in link.html page??

Thanks:)

Comment: Maybe you can use $('#result').load('link.html #page2'); to load only the page2 of the link.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that others have had this issue before but the only solution is to either combine all the pages into one HTML file or separate them all.

sourced from similar question:
[How to link to jquery mobile subpage from external page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961372/how-to-link-to-jquery-mobile-subpage-from-external-page)